# For loop with array of columns names and another array with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript-typings

have a way more performative to make this loop?

The `rows` have a array of array of strings

like:

```js
let rows = [
["col1val1", "09", "26", "1"],
["col1val2", "08", "59", "1"],
["col1val3", "09", "22", "1"]
];
```

And `columns` have the respective columns names

Like:

```js
let columnsNames = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];
```

## My actual code:

```js
        let _rows = [];
        this.rows.forEach((row: string[]) => {
            let _row = {};
            columnsNames.forEach((col: string, i) => {
                _row[col] = row[i];
            });
            _rows.push(_row);
        });
```

The objective is return a array of objects with yours columns names of respective value of `rows`

Like:

```js
let rows = [
    {
        col1: "eventName"
        col2: "09"
        col3: "26"
        col4: "1"
    },
    {
        col1: "eventName"
        col2: "08"
        col3: "59"
        col4: "1"
    },...
];
```

Comment: The most performant will be using good ol' fashioned `for` loops. Did you want that or *short* code which is probably using a combination of `map`/`reduce`

Comment: The ideia is not to "short" code, but make it more performative.

Comment: BTW youve chosen the second worse solution as the accepted answer. See my benchmarks below.

Comment: I changed for your solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to find the most performant code, it is important to benchmark. One thing you should always consider with javascript is any of the method-y ways of looping arrays will never perform as well as native for loops.  And you can squeeze a little extra out by caching the `length` so its not read each iteration.

So, the most performant solution will almost certainly be:

```js
let columnsNames = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];
let rows = [
["col1val1", "09", "26", "1"],
["col1val2", "08", "59", "1"],
["col1val3", "09", "22", "1"]
];


var _rows = [];
var rlen = rows.length;
var clen = columnsNames.length;
for(var i=0;i<rlen;i++){
    var _row = {};
    for(var c=0;c<clen;c++){
        _row[columnsNames[c]] = rows[i][c];
    }
    _rows.push(_row);
}

console.log(_rows);
```

I took the liberty of benchmarking this solution with the others given and as expected this comes out slightly better. Results will vary of course, based on the runtime environment.

https://jsperf.com/array-of-columns-names-and-another-array-with-values/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```js
let rows = [
  ["col1val1", "09", "26", "1"],
  ["col1val2", "08", "59", "1"],
  ["col1val3", "09", "22", "1"]
];

let columnsNames = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];

const newRows = rows.map(row => {
  const object = row.reduce((obj, entry, index) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [columnsNames[index]]: entry
    };
  }, {});

  return {
    ...object
  };
});

console.log(newRows);
```

Comment: `array.reduce` is commonly misused. Almost always when using `reduce` to construct an object, `Object.fromEntries` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why is it a misuse? Fact or opinion? - `Object.fromEntries` does work nicely here, not arguing. Just would like more perspective

Comment: Just personal opinion. It's just my experience that whenever I've written or seen code using `reduce` to construct an object, it's usually been cleaner to rewrite with `Object.fromEntries`.

Answer (score 0):

1 liner:

```js
let rows = [
  ["col1val1", "09", "26", "1"],
  ["col1val2", "08", "59", "1"],
  ["col1val3", "09", "22", "1"]
];
let columnsNames = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];

let out = rows.map(row => Object.fromEntries(columnsNames.map((col, i) => [col, row[i]])));
console.log(out);
```

BTW, thanks for a very clear minimum example, expected output, and attempted solution!

(edit) Here's a modification that avoids using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let rows = [
  ["col1val1", "09", "26", "1"],
  ["col1val2", "08", "59", "1"],
  ["col1val3", "09", "22", "1"]
];
let columnsNames = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"];

let objectFromEntries = properties =>
  properties.reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
    obj[key] = val;
    return obj;
  }, {});

let out = rows.map(row => objectFromEntries(columnsNames.map((col, i) => [col, row[i]])));
console.log(out);
```

Comment: thanks for compliment, for this sort way, if is a large array, not will be more slow?

Comment: If you're talking 1000's of elements, it's fine. If you're talking 100,000's of elements, then perhaps it may be noticeable and running some performance tests may be worthwhile.

Comment: That being said, this is just O(c*r) iterations and O(r) invocations of `Object.fromEntries`. I can't think of a more performant alternative.

Comment: I using it for 100k more elements. In angular (ts) the ```Object.fromEntries``` not work because not exists in typescript this function for objects. The message: "TS2339: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'."

Comment: That's an "intentional" bug of typescript. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32803. I'm not familiar with typescript but it should have a way to skip checking some lines.

Comment: and using the same code, but changing the ```fromEntries``` to ```entries``` function result in a wrong return: ```0: Array(4)
0: Array(2)
0: "0"
1: Array(2)
0: "col1"
1: "value1"```

Comment: `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` are opposites, not equivalents. I've added a 2nd version that polyfills `Object.fromEntries`.

Comment: Note that from `Object.fromEntries` might not work in Internet Explorer, Edge and some mobile browsers when looking at the [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility). However this might be outdated since the specification status states "draft" (2), while it says "finished" (4) when looking at the [official proposal GitHub](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-from-entries). I can't test those browsers since I currently don't have Internet Explorer nor Edge installed on this machine.